# Surface integral over a shifted sphere

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates

Let $v$ be a vector field defined in **$R^3$**.
$v(x)=C*x/|x|$ where $C$ is a constant.
Let $S$ be the sphere of radius $a$ and center $(b,0,0)$.
Compute $\int_{S}{F\cdot n \ dS}$ where $n$ is the normal vector to the surface of $S$.
I tried to solve this by using a coordinate transformation so that the origin is in the center of the sphere.
$v'(x)=C*(x+b*e_x)/|x+b*e_x|$ was my new vector field und then I used spherical coordinates. But the integral was pretty difficult and I couln't solve it.
How do I solve this?

Comment: Do you know Gauß' divergence theorem?

Comment: Yes, I do. I tried it with the theorem, but the I couldn't solve it either.

Comment: You have an axis of symmetry. Then trying cylindrical coordinates often helps.